# Listview widget yii2, how to change the index value

Tags: yii2

As you can use a index value inside the view when using a listview widget I wanted to change this index value as I use the same view on different places, so not every element that I use have the same index on the pages.

somepage.php

```
echo ListView::widget([
    'summary' => false,
    'viewParams' => [
        'url' => '',
    ],

    'index' => 'index + 4',//the idea

    'options' => [
            'class' => 'xxxx',
    ],
    'itemOptions'=> [
        'class' => 'xxxx',
    ],
    'itemView' => '@frontend/views/product/_item_product_small',
    'dataProvider' => $provider,
]);
```

frontend/views/product/_item_product_small.php

```
 <div data-index="<?=$index?>">
  // content
 </div>
```

Comment: as far as i know there isnt any property named `index` for the `ListView` widget are you using [`yii\widgets\ListView`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-listview) ?

Comment: yes this is what im using, and you can use $index inside the view

Comment: @user759235 What do you really want to achieve? You could do it another way.

Comment: can you please reformat the code and add it the way you are using it as looking at the code it looks like you are setting a property `index` for the `ListView` which does not exist. i still couldnot completly understand what yo uare trying to achieve, as it confuses. add the view code separately so that it is more readable

Comment: the code used is above, the rest of the code is not related(puur html). As the listview loops items each item has an index, which can be used inside the view with $index

Comment: Is this `<div data-index="<?php echo $index + 4; ?>">content</div>` what you want?

Comment: No i cant do it this way as the view file is used multiple times, so I cant set the index inside the view file itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create intermediate view for such cases:

*`somepage.php`*

```
echo ListView::widget([
    // ...
    'itemView' => '_view',
]);
```

*`_view.php`*

```
$this->render('@frontend/views/product/_item_product_small', ['index' => $index + 4]);
```